# Access object created in AuthenticationFilter from the Web API Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, actionfilterattribute

I have implemented a HMAC authentication filter (as per [this article](http://bitoftech.net/2014/12/15/secure-asp-net-web-api-using-api-key-authentication-hmac-authentication/)) in a Web API 2 project. The article uses static keys for demo purposes so I have modified the filter to look up the Private API Key from a database using an 'AppId' Guid. This works nicely as I'm able to load the appropriate account for that AppId entry. But I would like to know if it's possible to access the "Account" object created in the authentication filter class in my controller.

This is how I declared the object:

```
public class HMACAuthenticationAttribute : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter
    {
        private static Dictionary<string, string> allowedApps = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        public DummyAccount account = new DummyAccount();
    }
```

And later down in the code:

```
// Load account and its private API Key
                    account = accountService.GetByAppId(Guid.Parse(appId), session);

                    if (account == null)
                    {
                        context.ErrorResult = new UnauthorizedResult(new AuthenticationHeaderValue[0], context.Request);
                    }

                    // If we find the account, we add to allowedApps the AppId/PrivateKey pair
                    allowedApps.Add(account.AppId.ToString(), account.ApiKey);
```

Now in my WebApi Controller, the code looks like this:

```
        [HMACAuthentication]
        [HttpPost]
        public RatingDto Post(SearchTrackDto searchedTrack)
        {

            // Access 'account' object here?

        }
```

My expectation is that I can somehow access the account object directly so I don't have to parse the request again and make a second database query. Would storing the object in the Request.Context be the way to go? What alternative is there?

Answer (score 0):

You could try implementing a cache. The AuthenticationFilter is supposed to validate each Request, as the Context lifetime scope is as long as the requests dies.